# Create tag [nuxtjs]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

Please create a tag [nuxtjs](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nuxtjs) for the popular VueJS framework [nuxt.js](https://nuxtjs.org/).

Comment: Do you have question on this site to tag it with?  If not, it'll be destroyed automatically if there's also no tag wiki.  It's perhaps best to wait until a relevant question comes along before proposing a new tag.

Comment: @Jamal Thank you for your comment. I just wanted to improve this website. Please feel free to do with that tag whatever you would like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have created the tag [nuxt.js](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nuxt.js). You're very welcome to create a tag-wiki for it to guide users on what this tag entails.

Comment: Great! Thank you!!